# How Could I extract HDR gain Map from iPhone's Heic?

Tags: hdr, heic

with jpeg format, I know can use:

```
exiftool -b -MPImage2 test-lumen.jpg > depthMap.jpg
```

But if the format is Heic, there is any method can export the HDR gain Map?

Comment: here:  gist.github.com/kiding/fa4876ab4ddc797e3f18c71b3c2eeb3a

Answer (score 0):

You can install ([libheif](https://github.com/strukturag/libheif)) and do:

`heif-convert <source_file>.HEIC <result_file>.jpg`

It will save auxiliary images as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to extract Apple specific metadata first.

It's documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/images_and_pdf/applying_apple_hdr_effect_to_your_photos